# What causes this error: "address already known to kernel for another [busy] synchronizer type"?

Tags: macos, darwin

I have a customer who is getting their system log flooded with thousands of copies of this message:

**Jul 25 11:21:33 athayer-mbp13 kernel[0]: PSYNCH: pid[52893]: address already known to kernel for another [busy] synchronizer type**

The culprit is my app, but I can’t reproduce the problem and don’t have much of a clue to its cause. My app does disk searching, and this error happens about 15 hours into the life of the process. There is no excessive memory usage or file descriptor leakage. The app continues to operate normally, it’s just that these messages cause the system log to blow up to gigabyte proportions and fill up the boot disk.

I found the Darwin kernel code where the message is printed, but it’s only a clue, it doesn’t show the smoking gun:

http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/bsd/kern/pthread_support.c

> **FAILEDUSERTEST**("address already known to kernel for another (busy) synchronizer type\n”);

It’s in this function:

```
/* find kernel waitqueue, if not present create one. Grants a reference  */

int
ksyn_wqfind(user_addr_t mutex, uint32_t mgen, uint32_t ugen, uint32_t rw_wc, uint64_t tid, int flags, int wqtype, ksyn_wait_queue_t * kwqp)
```

Can anyone provide any insight into what’s going on?

Here’s the profile for the machine:

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:   MacBookPro12,1
Processor Name: Intel Core i5
Processor Speed:    2.7 GHz
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  2
L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
L3 Cache:   3 MB
Memory: 8 GB
Boot ROM Version:   MBP121.0167.B16
SMC Version (system):   2.28f7
Hardware UUID:  9205D058-90BF-541E-8E61-E75259ABC11F
```

System Software Overview:

```
System Version: OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Kernel Version: Darwin 15.4.0
Boot Volume:    Macintosh HD
Boot Mode:  Normal
Computer Name:  athayer-mbp13
User Name:  System Administrator (root)
Secure Virtual Memory:  Enabled
system_integrity:   integrity_enabled
Time since boot:    9 days 18:55
```

Comment: I got this error on my mac today and this page was the only semi-useful search result.  In my case, the error was caused by the CrashPlan backup service (CrashPlanService), and was using all CPU cores  to the max.  I had to kill -9 to get rid of it.   MacOS 10.13.4.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible Explanation

It's possible that you're being affected by an old kernel bug. If a pthread condition variable (the main component of a standard `pthread_mutex` family object) is allocated, but never waited on, there is a situation in which its object is never removed from a pthreads-internal registry on OSX.

If that happens, and if another mutex is later allocated that happens to end up in the same space in memory, and if that mutex is waited on, this error can occur, since the new mutex's ID will not match the one already present in its space. This is distinct from a reallocation issue where garbled/meaningless info is found instead of a valid ID.

### Workaround

The workaround is to ensure that you are calling a a wait function on all mutexes/condvars you create. Even a nanosecond wait will trigger "correct" destruction when it completes on a no-longer-used mutex. An example of the fix by the Chromium devs is linked below.

For example, you could wait one nanosecond/tick on a lock thus:

```
struct timespec time { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 1 };
pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np(
    &some_condition_handle,
    &some_lock_handle,
    time
);
```

### Confounding Factors

The kernel bug may not be the real issue. There are a lot of confounding factors here:

- The kernel source hasn't been published for 10.10 or 10.11, so the code being called that generates that error may not be the code that you found online.
- As a result of that, the kernel bug I mentioned may not still exist, or may not be reachable in the same way.
- The error line you published has parens (`()`) around the word "busy", but the source you found has square brackets (`[]`). The places in code that print out the two different messages are distinct from each other, so the problem lines might not be the ones you pointed out in your question.

### Relevant Links

- Article by the first (only?) person who has diagnosed this issue: http://rayne3d.com/blog/02-27-2014-rayne-weekly-devblog-4
- The problem gets exhibited in the pthread source (or it was, in pthread 105.1.4), visible at this link (search in the page for `13782056`): https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-105.1.4/src/pthread_cond.c
- An example fix like the workaround listed above was made by the Chromium team when they were affected by a similar (the same?) issue: https://codereview.chromium.org/1323293005
- The original Apple Developer Forum link appears to be defunct, though I might just be unable to access it: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/220316?tstart=0

Comment: Wow! I wouldn't have thought to see a blogpost I wrote referenced on StackOverflow. Guess I better make sure to preserve the blogs content now.

Comment: Thanks for the trenchant post! It was invaluable in finding the root of this issue. More amusing context: I think I'm the client that the questioner was referring to; I just got off of a conference call with someone else that works for Michael's company re: this same issue :p

Comment: Did this turn out to fix the issue?